# how to map a ManyToMany Map<Basic, Entity> with JPA (eclipselink)

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink

i need to persist a map with a basic key and a entity value. this runs, if i do not try to add the same second entity twice:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="THIRD_TABLE")
@MapKeyColumn(name="INTEGER_COLUMN", table="THIRD_TABLE")
private Map<Integer, SecondEntity> secondEntities = new HashMap<>();
```

but if i try (year1: secondE_1, year2: secondE_1) my app throws this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Violation of unique constraint SYS_PK_294: 
duplicate value(s) for column(s) FIRSTENTITY_ID,SECONDENTITY_ID in statement [INSERT INTO COVERANALYSIS_EXPENSERECORDSETS (secondentity_id, firstentity_id, INTEGER_COLUMN) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
Error Code: -104
```

seems like the mapkey isn't used as it should. i've tried some other annotations and endless google searches but nothing seems to work.

please help me.

Comment: EclipseLink doesn't allow duplicates in collections by default, though it should work here.  You will need to change your DDL for the join table so that the map key and foreign keys are used as a composite PK.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in EclipseLink that has been reported.

[Bug 344448 - wrong mapping of java.util.Map](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344448) .

Hibernate handles it OK.

Answer (score 0):

in the end i've installed a junction-helper-object in between.

the FirstEntity inverse maps the list:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="firstEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<SecondEntityJunction> secondEntities;
```

the SecondEntityJunction contains the parent Key, the year and the secondEntity FK:

```
@ManyToOne
private FirstEntity firstEntity;
private int year;
private SecondEntity secondEntity;
```

that's it.